# Does java io API allow to create file with all folder structure by single method invocation?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

my task:

input parameter - path to file. This path may not contain any folders. I want create all folder structure and create file.

my current decision:

```
File file = new File("D:\\nonexistingFolder\\folder2\\1.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

Is it possible to simplify this code? For example to replace 2 second lines with single

Comment: Why do you want to create an empty file? More usually you would want to write data to it, which requires more than one line of code anyway.

Comment: It is just task. I want to create empty file

Comment: You can write it yourself.

Comment: question about researching ready OOTB things. I don't like write own bycicles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Java has a short hand for that. You need to use `mkdirs()` method for this. Java 7 introduced a [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class which has createDirectories method, but that too doesn't satisfy your requirement. However you can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/index.html) [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class. Eg:

```
FileOutputStream file = FileUtils.openOutputStream(new File("D:\\nonexistingFolder\\folder2\\1.txt"));
```

This will create intermediate folders and file for you. Apparantly it'll be using all those step underneat. Its just a personal choice whether or not to add a third party library for just avoiding 2 lines of code.